# When is it appropriate to create a static property instead of an instance in javascript objects?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I don't really understand how/when to use javascript prototypes. I understand the difference between these two ways of assigning properties:

**Static property**

```
var Date = function () {};
Date.setTime = function (key) {
};
Date.updateTime = function (key, value) {
};
```

setTime and updateTime are properties directly added to the Date object.

**Assigning property to an instance prototype**

```
var Date = function () {};
Date.prototype.setTime = function (key) {
};
Date.prototype.updateTime = function (key, value) {
};
```

setTime and updateTime are defined properties that instances of Date will inherit.

**My question:** How do you know when you should be assigning properties to an instance/prototype or directly to the object (static variable)? When should I decide to assign a variable directly to an object vs making it available to all instances?

Comment: Well something like `Date.now()` makes sense without any reference to any particular existing Date instance, while `Date.prototype.getFullYear()` doesn't. Is that what you're asking about?

Comment: @Pointy My question is when should I decide to assign a variable directly to an object vs making it available to all instances?

Comment: If the function doesn't have anything to do with any particular instance, then it can go on the constructor itself. If the function only makes sense when an instance is involved (like, it has to reference `this.something` in the code), then it **has** to be on the prototype and available to instances.

Answer (score 2):

Depends completely on what you are wanting to do with the object. If you want instances of the object to be able to use the method with their own properties, you'll want the prototype to have the methods. Otherwise, if you're creating a utility class of some sort where you don't want the class to keep any state, then you should probably just add static methods.

Basically, if you want instances of the object to be able to use their own state in the method, then set the method on the prototype.

```js
var MyObj = function(prop) {
  this.myProp = prop;
}
MyObj.static = function() {
  console.log('This is static ' + this.myProp);
}
MyObj.prototype.dynamic = function() {
  console.log('This is dynamic ' + this.myProp);
}

var myInstance = new MyObj('wow!');

MyObj.static(); // 'This is static undefined'
// MyObj.dynamic(); // Not a function

// myInstance.static(); // Not a function either
myInstance.dynamic(); // 'This is dynamic wow!'
```

Comment: Thanks this was helpful. I understand the difference, but it's hard to implement this in my code since I am new to it.